# MongoDB VPS client_ip_address

Tags: mongodb, vps

I'm setting up a MongoDB on a VPS that will run a Private network so that my apps on another VPS will be able to access it. I'm following the excellent Digital Ocean documentation, however, I'm not sure what `client_ip_address` is referring to. Does this mean the MongoDB VPS ip, the MongoDB VPS private network ip or the app VPS ip. 
I'm a noob when it comes to databases.

> Next, we'll allow access to the default MongoDB port, 27017, but
>   restrict that access to a specific host. If you've changed the default
>   port, be sure to update it in the command below.
>
> `sudo ufw allow from client_ip_address to any port 27017`

Comment: It is referring to the IP of client that will try to access the mongo remotely

Comment: So that would be the IP of the VPS where my apps are hosted?

Comment: yes, that would be the case. you are essentially telling the firewall on mongo host to allow a client with a specific IP to hit a specific port on the mongo host